# how did Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS address to the fix for RIDL and Fallout: MDS attacks?

Tags: intel, vulnerability

I am just wondering if there were anything completed from Ubuntu side with the version 18.04.2 LTS to address to the RIDL and Fallout: MDS attacks.

Thanks.

Comment: [CVE numbers](https://cve.mitre.org/about/faqs.html) are usually much more useful for this kind of question than names. Not every important vulnerability has a snazzy name.

Answer (score 1):

[CVE-2018-12127](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-12127.html)?

The link to the CVE has a list Ubuntu versions and packages affected and changed. A lot are DNE (does not exist).

> Priority High
>
> Description
>
> Microarchitectural Load Port Data Sampling (MLPDS): Load ports on some
> microprocessors utilizing speculative execution may allow an authenticated
> user to potentially enable information disclosure via a side channel with
> local access. A list of impacted products can be found here:
> https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/corporate-information/SA00233-microcode-update-guidance_05132019.pdf

References

- https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-12127
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3977-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3978-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3979-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3980-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3981-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3982-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3983-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3982-2
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3980-2
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3984-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3981-2
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3983-2
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3985-1
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3985-2
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3977-2
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3977-3